# How to get the module id from TM_FILEPATH in a vscode snippet?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Is there a way to convert the value of the `TM_FILEPATH` variable to a module id?

I would like to create a snippet that resolves the module id:

`d:\myrepo\client\store\calc.ts => <amd-module name="store/calc" />`

```
{
    "prefix": "amd-module-name",
    "body": [
        "/// <amd-module name=\"${TM_FILEPATH/.*client\\\\(.*)\\..*$/$1/}\" />\n"
    ]
}
```

The snipped above gives me `<amd-module name="store\calc" />` but how do I get rid of the back slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"someName" : {
    "prefix": "amd-module-name",
    "body": [
        "/// <amd-module name=\"${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*client[\\\\\\/])?([^\\/\\\\]*)([\\/\\\\])?/$2${3:+\/}/g}\/$TM_FILENAME_BASE\" />\n",
    ]
  },
```

It is lengthy but fairly powerful (and all those necessary double-escapings!).

This will handle directories with \ or / path separators.

`[\\\\\\/]` means either a \ or a /  (you just need 3 escaping backslashes before a \ in an vscode snippet and two before a /)!!

So `[^\\/\\\\]*` means get characters until you hit a slash.

This regex will work with any number of directories under "`client`".  Thanks in part to the `global regex modifier g` .

```
d:\myrepo\client\store\subStore\calc.ts => <amd-module name="store/subStore/calc" />
```

This part is nice: `$2${3:+\/}`  that means insert matching group 2 and only if there is a matching group 3 add a backslash /.  This comes into play accounting for the last directory with the file in it and changing the captured group 3 \ to a / as you want.